# Maven dependency on another local project: all ok but compiler does not see jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-module

I have two projects, let's say A and B, in the same directory `dir`. B is a parent project to its module C. C is dependent on A. Directory structure:

```
dir/
    A/
    B/
       C/
```

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29712865/8564676) method create a project with modules and to show, that C is dependent on A. After doing this, Netbeans starts to see packages of A in C, e.g. it shows no missing packages, gives hints on using classes from A in C. If I put A as a module of B, `mvn clean install` says that maven reactor found the correct order of compiling projects and compiles them in the order A, B, C. `mvn dependency:tree` shows that `groupB:C:jar:0.0.1` has a child node `groupA:A:jar:0.0.1:compile`.

I am not sure if A can be a module of B, because A has another parent (Spring boot). Thus, I try another variant: remove A from modules of B, then `mvn clean install` in A, so that (I guess) the jar it produces goes to the local repo. Both variants seem to be ok for maven and Netbeans, but not for the compiler. During compilation, C does not see the packages of A.

I did `mvn clean install` in any of the three projects. The dependency in C must have exact properties of A or a dependency error is produced in Maven. It seems that both Netbeans' hinting mechanism and Maven think that A is a library of C. It is only the compiler who doesn't see it. I guess that I did a newbie error. What can it be?

Relevant fragments of the `pom.xml` involved:

A:

```
   <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>groupA</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>projectA</name>
    <description>project A</description>
```

B: (I tried variants with A being a module of B commented out or not)

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
</parent>
<groupId>groupB</groupId>
<artifactId>B</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>projectB</name>
<description>project B</description>

<modules>
        <!--module>../A</module-->
        <module>C</module>
</modules>
```

C:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>groupB</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
</parent>
<groupId>groupB</groupId>
<artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>projectC</name>
<description>project C</description>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>groupA</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Best would be to create an example project/setup on github or alike...

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that A's jar is in the dependency tree, I searched for A's classes in that jar. It turned out, there aren't any. Instead, they are packaged separately in `groupA.A.jar.original`. As it turned out, it was ok to make Spring Boot a parent of A, even if A is just a library. Thanks to this, all Spring dependencies get versions automatically from the parent. However, I also included `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in A, not knowing what it is for. That plugin has a `repackage` goal which prepares a Spring Boot application. It was the cause of creating these two jars, and in effect, C not seeing classes of A. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53138576/8564676) for more details.

Keeping Spring Boot as a parent but removing the plugin made C see classes of A.